# How can I make this react component reusable and pass a dynamic initial state?

Tags: reactjs, forms, input, refactoring

I have created this dynamic input table, but I want to make it reusable and more dynamic. Here, the name and age are static. If I want to send the name, age, country, region, etc. as props, this code won't work. How can I do this?
Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';

const DynamicTable = () => {
  const [fields, setFields] = useState([{ name: '', age: 0 }]);

  const onChangeHandler = (e, index) => {
    let name = '';
    let age = 0;
    if (e.target.name === 'name') {
      name = e.target.value;
      console.log(name, age);
    } else {
      age = e.target.value;
      console.log(name, age);
    }
    // Set Field Value
    const newFields = fields.map((item, i) => {
      if (index === i) {
        if (e.target.name === 'name') {
          return { ...item, name };
        } else {
          return { ...item, age };
        }
      } else {
        return item;
      }
    });
    setFields(newFields);
    console.log(newFields);
  };

  // For delete button
  const deleteHandler = (index) => {
    const newField = fields.filter((item, i) => i !== index);
    setFields(newField);
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => setFields([...fields, { name: '', age: 0 }])}>
          Add
        </button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {fields.map((item, index) => (
            <tr key={index}>
              <td>
                Name:
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='name'
                  onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e, index)}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                Age:
                <input
                  type='text'
                  name='age'
                  onChange={(e) => onChangeHandler(e, index)}
                />
              </td>
              <td>
                <button onClick={() => deleteHandler(index)}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <button onClick={() => console.log(fields)}>Submit</button>
      </div>
      {/* Test input value working correctly */}
      <div>
        {fields.map((item) => (
          <p>
            {item.name} - {item.age}
          </p>
        ))}
      </div>
      {/* ---- */}
    </div>
  );
};

export default DynamicTable;
```

Note: It would be great if we can delete and add rows based on the checkbox. Also, applying CSS throw props for buttons or other elements would be awesome.

Comment: In your **Note**, it looks like you're demanding

Comment: Have you tried... passing the props and setting the initial state value?

Comment: @DrewReese answer is correct. You can also add a `useEffect` which checks whether the provided initial state from prop has been changed in consequent renders or not, and throws an error if it has been changed. Or make it a custom hook...

Comment: @DrewReese Thanks for your reply. I have tried, but don't understand how I can make it dynamic, cause, I have taken input field name to set the input value to state. If I take the initial state from props, how will I set the input field name. If I can't set the name, then I won't be able use the if else logic using e.target.name.

Comment: @GermaVinsmoke Sorry for my bad English. Actually, it's not my demand and it's not important for me. But if it is possible, this code may be helpful for lots of people. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make the fields dynamic and the component overall more generic:

1. Pass a `fields` prop object that defines the fields for a single row.
2. Create a utility that wraps a fields object with an `id` for easy identification (*this comes in handy when mutating the array rows since using an array index won't work*).
3. Adjust handlers to manage rows by `id` and the new state shape.

Code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from "uuid";
import "./styles.css";

const createFieldsObject = (fields) => ({
  id: uuidV4(), // <-- generate unique Id, can use anything really
  fields
});

const DynamicTable = ({ fields }) => {
  const [fieldRows, setFieldRows] = useState([createFieldsObject(fields)]);

  const onChangeHandler = (id) => (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setFieldRows((rows) =>
      rows.map((row) =>
        row.id === id
          ? {
              ...row,
              fields: {
                ...row.fields,
                [name]: value
              }
            }
          : row
      )
    );
  };

  const addHandler = () =>
    setFieldRows((rows) => [...rows, createFieldsObject(fields)]);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => () =>
    setFieldRows((rows) => rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));

  const getFieldRows = () => fieldRows.map(({ fields }) => fields);

  const submitHandler = e => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(getFieldRows());
  }

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addHandler}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {fieldRows.map(({ id, fields }, index) => (
            <tr key={id}>
              {Object.entries(fields).map(([key, value]) => (
                <td key={key}>
                  {key}:
                  <input
                    type="text"
                    name={key}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler(id)}
                    value={value}
                  />
                </td>
              ))}
              <td>
                <button onClick={deleteHandler(id)}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </div>
      {/* Test input value working correctly */}
      <div>
        {fieldRows.map(({ id, fields }) => (
          <p key={id}>{Object.values(fields).join(" - ")}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
      {/* ---- */}
    </form>
  );
};
```

Example usage:

```
<DynamicTable fields={{ Name: "", Age: 0 }} />
<DynamicTable fields={{ Name: "", Age: 0, Location: "" }} />
```

[image: Edit how-can-i-make-this-react-component-reusable-and-pass-a-dynamic-initial-state]

Comment: This code works perfectly. Is it possible to validate this dynamic data both server and client side? I use mongoose and joi in server-side.

Comment: @shohagkhan I don't see why not. Presumably you should also be passing in an `onSubmit`/`handleSubmit` callback, and it'd be trivial to add validation, either in the `onChange` or `onSubmit`, or both even. The `getFieldRows` was just a simple example for "unpacking" the field data back out of the field row object container.

Comment: @shohagkhan It's late for me, but if you leave the details in a chat, or ask a new SO question and link it here, I will take a look in the morning.

Comment: I just create a SO question and copied your code there. When you are available [please take a look at the link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65707934/how-to-validate-dynamic-field-data-on-the-react-client-side-and-node-server-side).

Comment: @shohagkhan Sorry for delay. Looks like you shared *your* code in that new SO question. In the meantime, here's a quick dirty sandbox [demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-can-i-make-this-react-component-reusable-and-pass-a-dynamic-initial-state-forked-1heiq?file=/src/App.js) to what I was referring to. Pass in callbacks for validation/submit functions to receive the form data.

Comment: Thanks a lot brother, you are not late. I have no hurry. I just edited the SO question with your code.