# How can I validate dynamic field data on the React client-side and Node.js server-side?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, express, validation

I have created a dynamic input field in the React component, but don't know how to validate this dynamic field data on the client-side when onChange and onSubmit event occurred. I usually use [Joi](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-use-joi-for-node-api-schema-validation) or [Yup](https://github.com/jquense/yup) to validate data, but don't know how I can validate dynamic field data.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { v4 as uuidV4 } from 'uuid';
import './styles.css';

const createFieldsObject = (fields) => ({
  id: uuidV4(),
  fields,
});

const DynamicTable = ({ fields }) => {
  const [fieldRows, setFieldRows] = useState([createFieldsObject(fields)]);

  const onChangeHandler = (id) => (e) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setFieldRows((rows) =>
      rows.map((row) =>
        row.id === id
          ? {
              ...row,
              fields: {
                ...row.fields,
                [name]: value,
              },
            }
          : row
      )
    );
  };

  const addHandler = () =>
    setFieldRows((rows) => [...rows, createFieldsObject(fields)]);

  const deleteHandler = (id) => () =>
    setFieldRows((rows) => rows.filter((row) => row.id !== id));

  const getFieldRows = () => fieldRows.map(({ fields }) => fields);

  const submitHandler = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log(getFieldRows());
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={submitHandler}>
      <div>
        <button onClick={addHandler}>Add</button>
      </div>
      <table>
        <tbody>
          {fieldRows.map(({ id, fields }, index) => (
            <tr key={id}>
              {Object.entries(fields).map(([key, value]) => (
                <td key={key}>
                  {key}:
                  <input
                    type='text'
                    name={key}
                    onChange={onChangeHandler(id)}
                    value={value}
                  />
                </td>
              ))}
              <td>
                <button onClick={deleteHandler(id)}>Delete</button>
              </td>
            </tr>
          ))}
        </tbody>
      </table>
      <div>
        <button type='submit'>Submit</button>
      </div>
      {/* Test input value working correctly */}
      <div>
        {fieldRows.map(({ id, fields }) => (
          <p key={id}>{Object.values(fields).join(' - ')}</p>
        ))}
      </div>
      {/* ---- */}
    </form>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className='App'>
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <h2>Start editing to see some magic happen!</h2>

      <DynamicTable fields={{ Name: '', Age: 0 }} />
      <DynamicTable fields={{ Name: '', Age: 42, Location: '', country: '' }} />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I also don't know how I will validate data on the server side.

```
import express from 'express';
const Joi = require('joi');
const router = express.Router();

router.post('/dynamic_data', async (req, res) => {
  // Don't know how to validate on server-side
});

export default router;
```

Comment: You have a chance to do so in the respective handlers. It depends on how you want to validate it: if you want to block field modification for a non accepted input or if you want to show a message, or both. Which do you want to use?

Comment: In the backend, you said you usually use Joi. Do it normally, or at least show how you use it normally and how it fails, and then we will be able to spot any problem.

Comment: I just want to show a message and also want to keep safe my database from malicious code. It is not necessary for me to use joi. I am not so skilled. So, it's difficult for me to understand the way of validating dynamic fields for both client and server side.

Comment: In the **frontend**: add a state for each value to validate. When the value changes (in its handler), if validation fails, set the validation state for this value to false. Use this state in the render to conditionally show a message (next to it's input or in the form header or next to the submit button). Also, if any validation fails, don't allow submitting in `submitHandler` (and possibly by disabling/hiding the submit button).

Comment: In your `submitHandler` I would expect to see an HTTP action (`fetch`, `axios` or something similar), which would need to be called if validation is successful.

Comment: `I am not so skilled`: Not needed, but it's better for us (your helpers) to spot problems than doing the full job.